# How to group by hierarchical data in pandas/sql?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, group-by

I have a problem on hierarchy.i have data  like this.

```
   id       performance_rating     parent_id     level
   111           8                   null         0 
   122           3                   null         0
   123           9                   null         0
   254           5                   111          1
   265           8                   111          1
   298           7                   122          1
   220           6                   123          1
   305           5                   298          2
   395           8                   220          2
   ...           ...                 ...         ...
   654           4                   562          5
```

the id is person unique identity.
performance_rating is his rating out of 10
parent_id is the id of the person who is working above the corresponding id.

I need to find out the average rating of an individual tree(111,122,123).

what I tried is separate data frame according to levels. Then merge it and groupby. But it is quite long.

Comment: What do you mean by `roll up`
?

Comment: the average for all the child under that id

Answer (score 2):

there will be a few different ways to do this - here's an ugly solution.

We use a while and for loop over a function to "back-level" each column of the dataframe:
This requires that we first set 'id' as index and sort by 'level', descending. It also requires no duplicate IDs. Here goes:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df = df.sort_values(by='level', ascending=False)

for i in df.index:
    while df.loc[i, 'level'] > 1:
        old_pid = df.loc[i, 'parent_id']
        df.loc[i, 'parent_id'] = df.loc[old_pid, 'parent_id']
        old_level = df.loc[i,'level']
        df.loc[i, 'level'] = old_level - 1
```

This way, no matter how many levels there are, we are left with everything at level 1 of hierarchy and can then do:

```
grouped = df.groupby('parent_id').mean()
```

(or whatever variation of that you need)
I hope that helps!